# Hot To Auto Install .Net With My Installer To Run My Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, console-application

I have created a Console Application With C# In my PC Its Running Properly But When i Install it on my Client PC it shows it need to install .net But the problem is that they dont access to internet so how can i attach and install .net while my installer running(.MSI)

Comment: If you are targeting a recent .net version, why not just [publish a self contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) application?

Comment: i am using windows installer to install my Application not publishing

Comment: Which installer you're using? You can use bootstrapper (.exe) which will contain your msi and .Net setup as pre-requisite.

Comment: i am using windows setup project

Comment: @Viv can you briefly Guide me to do that?

Comment: I found below link which might be useful in your case.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2022

please select appropriate Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 1):

In .net 6 you can create a self-contained single executable file by publishing like this:

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained true
```

See: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/11/10/single-file-apps-in-net-6/

Comment: i have a installer with some files and folders to run my application so how to add   the self contained exicutble with that installer

Comment: @C47_C0D3R And the self-contained executable would be one of these “some files and folders”. What would be the issue here?

Comment: @C47_C0D3R: how are you currenty adding files to the installer?

Comment: using installer to create folder and adding files to it

Comment: in that case, as ckuri said, just add the self-contained exe to it as well